# Kubernetes plugin in Jenkins : Failed to authenticate with proxy

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I created Kubernetes cloud and tried to use Credentials(Remote Cluster).

( Create Credential Reference : https://illya-chekrygin.com/2017/08/26/configuring-certificates-for-jenkins-kubernetes-plugin-0-12/ )

But when I press "Test Connection", I get the following error:

```
Error testing connection https://10.242.104.162:6443: java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy
```

[image]

Kubernetest environment:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:           19.03.6
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        369ce74a3c
 Built:             Fri Feb 28 23:45:43 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.6
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       369ce74a3c
  Built:            Wed Feb 19 01:06:16 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.3.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.2
  GitCommit:
 runc:
  Version:          spec: 1.0.1-dev
  GitCommit:
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:
```

- kubectl version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.1", GitCommit:"206bcadf021e76c27513500ca24182692aabd17e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-09-09T11:26:42Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.1", GitCommit:"206bcadf021e76c27513500ca24182692aabd17e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-09-09T11:18:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Does anyone know the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: Where is your Jenkins running?

Comment: Run in a container. Different from kubernetes server.

Comment: a year ago I wrote big answer on how to use and set-up credentials. Please use, that is not similar case, but maybe you will find something useful there for you. Let me know anyway.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57240391/how-to-integrate-amazon-eks-and-jenkins/57593820#57593820